# Access violation at address in module 'executable.exe'. Read of address

Tags: c++builder, access-violation

I've read some problems with "Access Violation" on the net but this is very weird for me

I have tested some "solutions" but with no results

This is the piece of code:

```
TDateTime CFileVersionInfo::GetFileDate() const
{
    FILETIME local;
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    TDateTime res;

    FILETIME    ft;
    ft.dwLowDateTime = m_FileInfo.dwFileDateLS;
    ft.dwHighDateTime = m_FileInfo.dwFileDateMS;

    FileTimeToLocalFileTime(&ft, &local);
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&local, &st) ;
    //GetLocalTime(st);
    res = SystemTimeToDateTime(st) ;

    return res;
}
```

I can Make or Build the program with no problems but when I run the program it show me the Access Violation error, if I comment the function:

```
// TDateTime dateTime = fvi.GetFileDate();
```

The program run perfectly

I'm not a C++ pro I just want to make a program for personal use so I ask this question to expert

**EDIT:**

I've resolved the problem

```
TDateTime CFileVersionInfo::GetFileDate() const
{
    _FILETIME local;
    _SYSTEMTIME st;
    TDateTime res;

    FILETIME    ft;
    ft.dwLowDateTime = m_FileInfo.dwFileDateLS;
    ft.dwHighDateTime = m_FileInfo.dwFileDateMS;

    FileTimeToLocalFileTime(&ft, &local);
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&local, &st) ;
    GetLocalTime(&st);           // <-- This is the solution.. for now...
    res = SystemTimeToDateTime(st) ;

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the problem

```
TDateTime CFileVersionInfo::GetFileDate() const
{
    _FILETIME local;
    _SYSTEMTIME st;
    TDateTime res;

    FILETIME    ft;
    ft.dwLowDateTime = m_FileInfo.dwFileDateLS;
    ft.dwHighDateTime = m_FileInfo.dwFileDateMS;

    FileTimeToLocalFileTime(&ft, &local);
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&local, &st) ;
    GetLocalTime(&st);           // <-- This is the solution.. for now...
    res = SystemTimeToDateTime(st) ;

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing any error checking to make sure the API conversions are succeeding, so you could be trying to convert trash data.  Always check for errors, eg:

```
TDateTime CFileVersionInfo::GetFileDate() const
{
    FILETIME local;
    SYSTEMTIME st;

    FILETIME ft;
    ft.dwLowDateTime = m_FileInfo.dwFileDateLS;
    ft.dwHighDateTime = m_FileInfo.dwFileDateMS;

    if( FileTimeToLocalFileTime(&ft, &local) )
    {
        if( FileTimeToSystemTime(&local, &st) )
            return SystemTimeToDateTime(st);
    }

    return 0.0;
}
```